# How Can I change objects name by a loop in C lang?

Tags: c

How Can I change objects name by a loop?

I want create a light effect like knight-rider's one. With a PIC

I thought instead of turning on and off manually to use a loop for change RB line number.

I want to change the last number of this Port line name: like RB01 RB02 like this

my code is like this

```
for(int i = 0; i>6 ; i++ ){

PORTB = 0X00;
RB+i = 1;

}
```

Are there any kind of method do something like this? thanks

Comment: Most MCU I/O is done with bit-wise operations.  You can't do this in C.  I am more familiar with AVR Win32 C library, but I am sure PIC is similar.  There should be #defines in a header file somewhere that you can look it.

Comment: @LeorA Those statements are true but incongruous. You can do exactly what he's asking by using bitwise operations. You cannot do it by renaming an identifier in a `for` loop, but that doesn't matter because it's so easy with bitwise operations. (For the sake of argument though, you could do it by renaming the identifier in a *preprocessor* loop.)

Comment: +1 for Knight Rider. Simple engineering, marketing genius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `RB01`, `RB02`, etc are just convenient `#define`s for accessing the bits in `PORTB`, you can write the loop with bitwise arithmetic and not use `RB0*` at all.

```
for ( int i = 0; i != 6; ++ i ) {
    PORTB = 1 << i; /* one light at a time */
    /* or */
    PORTB = ( 1 << i + 1 ) - 1; /* light all in sequence */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not very elegant, but one way is to do it like this:

```
PORTB = 0x00;
for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    RB00 = (i == 0);
    RB01 = (i == 1);
    RB02 = (i == 2);
    RB03 = (i == 3);
    RB04 = (i == 4);
    RB05 = (i == 5);
    // note: you probably want to put a delay in here, e.g. 200 ms
}
```

If you want to keep the previous LEDs on each time you turn on a new one then you can do that like this:

```
PORTB = 0x00;
for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    RB00 = (i >= 0);
    RB01 = (i >= 1);
    RB02 = (i >= 2);
    RB03 = (i >= 3);
    RB04 = (i >= 4);
    RB05 = (i >= 5);
    // note: you probably want to put a delay in here, e.g. 200 ms
}
```

Comment: I can imagine the downvote happened because such code won't help the questioner to improve his microcontroller programming skills. It's simply a lot of writing work for nothing. As Potatoswatter said in his comment above, bitwise operations are the way to do it. Just because it works it doesn't have to be right. ;-)

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "right". ;-) The OP is evidently a complete beginner, so something that is simple, easy to understand, and works, is probably "right" in this context. Bitwise operations can wait for lesson #2...

Comment: Yeah, gotta agree with Paul. I mainly wrote my answer to back my comment for Leor's benefit.

Comment: @PaulR I do not agree because your solution simply brings the loop to absurdity. Why teach a beginner such a thinking? - It would had been even better to understand if you set up the LEDs with the wait in sequence and use the loop only for repeating the sequence. But anyway. It's another discussion.

Comment: @junix Consider that the loop will probably evolve into the MCU's main task loop with event handling, etc. And consider that in a commercial product you might not have the luxury of assuming the bits will be ideally placed, as the board layout and I/O pin constraints might dictate that they get rearranged, perhaps after the software is "finished." What Paul wrote is actually quite reasonable and professional.

Comment: @Potatoswatter As you mentioned yourself the OP is a beginner, so his I/Os are obviously ideally placed. So there is no reason to provide such a "hacky" solution. Even in the case you just described there are other ways to solve this. But I think this discussion runs out of scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to "generate" symbol names that way. You can use bit masks for manipulating the latch register of the port in question.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a table:

```
struct portbits
{
   sometype bit;   // Not quite sure what "RB0..RB5" actually translate to. 
};

struct portbits bits[] =
{
   RB00, 
   RB01, 
   RB02, 
   RB03, 
   RB04, 
   RB05, 
   RB06, 
   RB07, 
};

for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
   bits[i] = 1; 
}
```

Comment: `RB0*` are almost certainly preprocessor macros resolving to bitfield access expressions. No way to subscript, take a pointer, etc.

Comment: True, that may be the case. In which case one would have to understand that it actually does and then store some form of that in the table - or do something else...